# CircleCI API + Lambda - triggering a build

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, circleci

I cannot get Lambda to trigger a build/deploy in CircleCI.

How can I convert a curl command to an HTTP request in Lambda?

curl command that works in Postman:

```
https://circleci.com/api/v1.1/project/:vcs-type/:username/:project/tree/:branch?circle-token=:my-token
content-type: app/json
body: 
{
    "build_parameters": {
            "CIRCLE_JOB": "deploy_docker"
        }
}
```

My appropriate creds are in place and it works great from Postman.

Assuming everything is correct in postman, how would I transfer that to Lambda?

Currently:

```
var buttonClicked = slackJSON.actions[0].name
   const postOptions = {
    host: 'api.circleci.com',
    path:'/api/v1.1/projects/github/joha0033/scyte-bot-cid/tree/dev?circle-token=:'+ process.env.CIRCLE_TOKEN,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    build_parameters: {CIRCLE_JOB: "deploy-docker"},
    revisions: 'a511d5fcc4ebb09e50239a3f025807860f2a5e2d',
    
};

const deployInfo = () => {
    const deployData = {
        build_parameters: {
            CIRCLE_JOB: 'deploy_docker'
        }
    }
    
    return JSON.stringify(deployData)
}

const postHandler = () => {
    console.log('postHandler')
    const postReq = https.request(postOptions, function(res){
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', (chunk) => {
          console.log('Response: >--> ' + chunk);
        });
    })
    
    postReq.write(deployInfo())
    postReq.end()
}

callback(null, postHandler())
```

Is this even possible?

I'm getting this as a response:

> Response: >--> Oops, no such page.

Or can I create something somewhere in AWS that will trigger a curl command via api POST request?

Answer (score 1):

Postman is sending to `project` and your code sends it to `projects` - that might be the problem